# mocha : testing a signup process with email-verification framework

Tags: express, mocha.js, email-verification

I try to test my signup router post function which use email-verification framework,but mocha shows me the error message below : 
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of null**

This my code :

**function that invoke the error:**

```
nev.resendVerificationEmail(email,(err,userExist) =>{
if(err){
      return res.status(404).send('Error : resending verification email failed');}
if(userExist){
      res.json({message : 'An email has been sent to you , again. Please check it to verify your account'});
}else{
      res.json({message : 'Your verification code has expired . Please sign up again'});
```

**and this is the implementation of resendVerificationEmail function**

```
var resendVerificationEmail = function(email, callback) {
var query = {};
query[options.emailFieldName] = email;

options.tempUserModel.findOne(query, function(err, tempUser) { //this the error handler I guess
  if (err) {
    return callback(err, null);
  }

  // user found (i.e. user re-requested verification email before expiration)
  if (tempUser) {
    // generate new user token
    tempUser[options.URLFieldName] = randtoken.generate(options.URLLength);
    tempUser.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err, null);
      }

      sendVerificationEmail(getNestedValue(tempUser, options.emailFieldName), tempUser[options.URLFieldName], function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err, null);
        }
        return callback(null, true);
      });
    });

  } else {
    return callback(null, false);
  }
});
```

};

**and this is my spec**

```
describe(' SignUp : /POST Test with fake client request : ', () => {
    let req, res, statusCode, sendData,user;
    beforeEach((done) => {
        SignupModal.remove({}, (err) => {
            done();
        });

        user = {
            firstName : 'ben',
            secondName : 'wissem',
            username : 'wiss',
            email : 'xy@zt.sq',
            password : 'wissem'
        };
        res = {
            json: function (code, data) {
                statusCode = code;
                sendData = data;
            }
        };
    });

    it('should send 200 code', () => {
        chai.request(server)
            .post('/user/signup')
            .send(user)
            .end((err, res) => {
                res.statusCode.should.equal(200);
            });
    });
```

Can any one help me please ?!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to end-to-end test email verification try [EmailE2E.com](https://www.emaile2e.com?utm=stack43167260), it's a free API that let's you send and receive emails from randomly generated inboxes. It's perfect for Firebase, Amazon Cognito, or other OAuth providers that use email verification codes during sign up. It also has a Javascript client you can use with Mocha.